# Changes doing in psql shell doesn't show up in Datagrip session

Tags: postgresql, psql, datagrip

I have user `postgres` with database `postgres`. I connected to it from Datagrip, but what I do in datagrip doesn't show when I do psql commands, same holds vice-versa.

I do `sudo -su postgres psql` and `\c postgres`

In Datagrip datasource parameters:

```
Host: localhost
Database: postgres
User: postgres
password: ******
```

Comment: what is the port you are connecting from datagrip?

Comment: Thank you Chathura Buddhika, the port was the problem. Idk how stackoverflow works, can't mark your answer as the solution or even close the question as solved.

Comment: check this, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: You can click on gray check mark under the answer. (Then it will turn to a green).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check the port from DataGrip as well as psql and make sure they are same.

To check the port number from `psql` terminal run following SQL;

```
SELECT *
FROM pg_settings
WHERE name = 'port';
```

To check the port number of Datagrip, go to datasource configurations screen.

[image]